# Deal with exception from an outsider activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Ok, I'm working in a project that calls an activity outside my project as `startActivityForResult()` and I've got, a couple of times, an exception on the other app and there is no log of it, it just close the current activity and return to the activity before, is there a way to catch it or prevent of crashing?

Comment: No there is none.

Comment: If the other app crashes then the users will see a dialog "unfortunately xyz had to be stopped". If they return to your app afterwards, they at least will know the crash wasn't "your crash". I suppose (sorry, didn't test it) that your app will be called with onActivityResult() and result code RESULT_CANCELED. Of course, this result code will also show up if the users really canceled the operation. It depends on the workflow of your application what will be an appropriate reaction

Comment: @0X0nosugar, the method `onActivityResult()` is not called, looks like there is nothing to be done for now but fix the exception in the other app. Thanks!